# MATLAB empty cell(n,m) array of strings?

Tags: string, matlab, cell

What is the quickest way to create an empty cell array of strings ?

```
cell(n,m)
```

creates an empty cell array of double.

How about a similar command but creating empty strings ?

Comment: I have something like this: strEmptyCell = {''}; repmat(strEmptyCell,n,m); ... anything better than this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depends on what you want to achieve really. I guess the simplest method would be:

```
repmat({''},n,m);
```

Comment: This is the shortest way of writing it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes but Kavka's solution is faster for large cells

Comment: if you only work with 1D, this could be an (even shorter) alternative: `repelem({''},n);`

Answer (score 8):

Assignment to all cell elements using the colon operator will do the job:

```
m = 3; n = 5;
C = cell(m,n);
C(:) = {''}
```

Comment: Using `repmat` or `deal` is overkill. A simple assignment with colon operator works fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my 'deal' overkill! You get my vote. Tried to delete my answer but it does work like that apparently. Not sure repmat would be worst that assignment in that case though.

Comment: A link is needed to point to why repmat is slower... Possibly something like this? http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/

Answer (score 1):

The cell array created by cell(n,m) contains empty matrices, not doubles.
If you really need to pre populate your cell array with empty strings

```
test = cell(n,m);
test(:) = {''};
test(1,:) = {'1st row'};
test(:,1) = {'1st col'};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a super old post but I'd like to add an approach that might be working. I am not sure if it's working in an earlier version of MATLAB. I tried in 2018+ versions and it works. 
Instead of using `remat`, it seems even more convenient and intuitive to start a cell string array like this:

```
C(1:10) = {''} % Array of empty char
```

And the same approach can be used to generate cell array with other data types

```
C(1:10) = {""} % Array of empty string
C(1:10) = {[]} % Array of empty double, same as cell(1,10)
```

But be careful with scalers

```
C(1:10) = {1} % an 1x10 cell with all values = {[1]}
C(1:10) = 1 % !!!Error
C(1:10) = '1' % !!!Error
C(1:10) = [] % an 1x0 empty cell array
```